# border edge will not disappear

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm using a really nice third party circular progress bar (installed via nuget & v2.5.6403.13419) [Found here](https://github.com/falahati/CircularProgressBar/blob/master/README.md) that has no border property but it still insists on displaying a top and left hand border artifact as per my attached screenshot (from VS 2017) although in all the examples this is not the case. I can't figure out why this should be and have experimented with every setting I think may cause it to no avail. I've set the forms paint to

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
```

but no difference and I've run out of ideas and my searches for anything similar have turned up nothing. Can anyone suggest anything please?

[image]

Comment: I suggest to try resetting every single property to its default. One by one, until you find if something you have changed affects the display of the control. I have tried with a control without any property changed and it seems to be ok

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author of the control?

Comment: Are you adding the progressbar to a control that might have a border property set? Perhaps a usercontrol or panel or something?  I just grabbed the package on a new project, created a default new one, and am not getting a border on it... this does not show a border: public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var x = new CircularProgressBar.CircularProgressBar();
            this.Controls.Add(x);               
        }

Comment: Thanks for your replies: 
Steve: yes I've tried resetting all the controls to their default.
Blackwood, no not yet, but I will.
Aaron: That's a good point, yes is the answer as I have it in a panel, but then I tried adding a new control to the form with the same result.

I really appreciate your help. I'll try some more.